# How to eliminate the gray background of the tableview edit-cell

Tags: javafx, tableview

**Problem**

When you edit a table cell the row height usually becomes higher, which is *unwanted* behavior:

[image]

I managed to elimininate the height change with this css:

```
.text-field-table-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0;
}
.text-field-table-cell .text-field {
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0;
    -fx-background-color:yellow;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}
```

But the cell is still not filled fully with the TextField. There's a gray background visible:

[image]

**Question**

Does anyone know how to eliminate the gray background of the edit-cell? Either by colorizing it or by removing it.

**Code**

Here's the full code if someone wants to test it:

InlineEditingTableViewCSS.java

```
public class InlineEditingTableViewCSS extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<Data> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Data(1.,5.),
                new Data(2.,6.),
                new Data(3.,7.),
                new Data(4.,8.)
        );

    private TableView<Data> table;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // create edtiable table
        table = new TableView<Data>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        // column 1 contains numbers
        TableColumn<Data, Number> number1Col = new TableColumn<>("Number 1");
        number1Col.setMinWidth(100);
        number1Col.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.getValue().number1Property());
        number1Col.setCellFactory( createNumberCellFactory());

        // column 2 contains numbers
        TableColumn<Data, Number> number2Col = new TableColumn<>("Number 2");
        number2Col.setMinWidth(100);
        number2Col.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.getValue().number2Property());
        number2Col.setCellFactory( createNumberCellFactory());

        // add columns & data to table
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll( number1Col, number2Col);




        // switch to edit mode on keypress
        // this must be KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED so that the key gets forwarded to the editing cell; it wouldn't be forwarded on KEY_RELEASED
        table.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

                if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
//                  event.consume(); // don't consume the event or else the values won't be updated;
                    return;
                }

                // switch to edit mode on keypress, but only if we aren't already in edit mode
                if( table.getEditingCell() == null) {
                    if( event.getCode().isLetterKey() || event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {  

                        TablePosition focusedCellPosition = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
                        table.edit(focusedCellPosition.getRow(), focusedCellPosition.getTableColumn());

                    }
                }

            }
        });

        table.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

                if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    table.getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
                }
            }
        });     

        // single cell selection mode
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();




        // add nodes to stage
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 800,600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Number cell factory which converts strings to numbers and vice versa.
     * @return
     */
    private Callback<TableColumn<Data, Number>, TableCell<Data, Number>>  createNumberCellFactory() {

        Callback<TableColumn<Data, Number>, TableCell<Data, Number>> factory = TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn( new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                return Double.parseDouble(string);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {
                return object.toString();
            }
        });

        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * Table data container
     */
    public static class Data {

        private final SimpleDoubleProperty number1;
        private final SimpleDoubleProperty number2;

        private Data( Double number1, Double number2) {
            this.number1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(number1);
            this.number2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(number2);
        }

        public final DoubleProperty number1Property() {
            return this.number1;
        }

        public final double getNumber1() {
            return this.number1Property().get();
        }

        public final void setNumber1(final double number1) {
            this.number1Property().set(number1);
        }

        public final DoubleProperty number2Property() {
            return this.number2;
        }

        public final double getNumber2() {
            return this.number2Property().get();
        }

        public final void setNumber2(final double number2) {
            this.number2Property().set(number2);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

application.css

```
.text-field-table-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0;
}
.text-field-table-cell .text-field {
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0;
    -fx-background-color:yellow;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}
```

Or is there a good mechanism to find out which CSS is currently being used by a node?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to eliminate the gray background of the
>   edit-cell?

Set padding values for textfield:

```
.text-field-table-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0;
}
.text-field-table-cell .text-field {
    -fx-padding: 3 0 3 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0;
    -fx-background-color:yellow;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that takes away the background from the textfield and makes it look gray. I'm searching for the opposite, i. e. colorize the field in which the user is typing.

Comment: Thanks, but now the selection has the same color as the cell when it is in edit mode, i. e. yellow. Do you know how to prevent it? All I want is the entire cell colorized when you type in it in edit mode, the rest of the layout / css should remain as it is.

Comment: @Roland, I think the only option with css is to set padding of textfield. Otherwise need a custom tablecell with Java code.

Comment: I already tried that, didn't work out. Still, your solution with the transparency is still the best so far.

Comment: @Roland, the -fx-padding: 3 0 3 0; above seems almost ok on my observation.

Comment: Almost. But it makes the text appear not centered vertically, instead it's shifted upwards. I'm using your solution with the background-color being transparent, but with all padding set to 0. It's the best from all I've tried and seen. Obviously some compromises have to be made. Thanks.

Comment: You are JavaFx Maestro! Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to use this solution and keep textfield focus borders - usual blue borders?

Comment: @iJava try setting -fx-border-width: 1;

Comment: I did this way: -fx-border-width:1px; -fx-border-style:solid;-fx-border-color:-fx-focus-color;-fx-border-width: 1;  and decresed top and bottom padding. Thanks. I don't understand why modena developers didn't do it by default. Why do we have to apply extra efforts to do it NORMAL?